# Powershell - Invoke-RestMethod get VM name

Tags: azure, powershell

trying to list all Azure VM's using https://b-blog.info/en/monitoring-azure-resources-with-zabbix.html

```
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01" -f `
    $subscription_id, `
    $resource_group;
write-host $uri
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/111111-1111-111-11111-111/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01
```

this code gives output (currently have only one VM)

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop | select * | fl

value : {@{properties=; type=Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines; location=westeurope; id=/subscriptions/111111-222-1111-1111-111111/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test; name=test}}
```

this line (as per link above) gives nothing:

```
$a=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop | select * | fl ).content.properties;
```

write-host $a gives nothing
and next line is also empty (get VM name)

```
foreach ($machine in $machines) {
$uri = https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}?api-version=2017-12-01" -f `
        $subscription_id, `
        $resource_group, `
        $machine.name;
    write-host $machine.name
    }
```

Comment: did you tried `$a=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop).Value.properties` ?

Comment: @Avshalovm i get  `Id               : 1f5575ff-d701-4365-a6d1-7fa53b09262e
hardwareProfile    : @{vmSize=Standard_B1s}
storageProfile     : @{imageReference=; osDisk=; dataDisks=System.Object[]}
osProfile          : @{computerName=test; adminUsername=ja; linuxConfiguration=; secrets=System.Object[]}
networkProfile     : @{networkInterfaces=System.Object[]}
diagnosticsProfile : @{bootDiagnostics=}
provisioningState  : Succeeded`
how to extract computername (test) ?

Comment: Okay try this: `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10` and post the output here.

Comment: too lengthy output:https://1drv.ms/w/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJ0GkEdFp4K2wKmqzQ

Comment: Does this work `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop).value.properties.osProfile.computerName`

Comment: @JacobColvin, yes it works !!!, thank You ! i already found another solution and posted it as answer

Comment: I'm leaving mine since the usage of FL also would have broken your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FL formats the object as a string, thus you cannot expand any properties from it.

The `Select * | FL` in your case is unnecessary and only impedes you. Removing it should get data to start returning.

EDIT: I got the correct property name just from looking through your JSON.

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop).value.properties.osProfile.computerName
```

Answer (score 0):

@Avshalom I found solution thanks to you (leave only Value property):

```
$a=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $azure_header -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop).Value
Write-Host $a.name

output:test
```